# Django - saving form to the built in database SQLite

Tags: python, django

This is my first time using Django and I am very simply trying to save text to the database. I have created the table inputs in the database.

I am getting the following error;

[Error - Page not found (404)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1jrj.png)

My code is as follows;

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Input(models.Model):
    waist = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "{0} {1} {2}".format(
        self, self.waist, self.height)
```

**forms.py**

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Input
    fields ={
    'waist',
    'height'
    }
```

**views.py**

```
def InputView(request):
if request.POST:
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('account/input')
else:
    form = InputForm()


    args = {'form' : form}

    return render(request,'accounts/input.html', args)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^input/$',views.InputView, name='view_input')
```

**input.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block head %}

<title> Edit Profile </title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h1> Enter Body Details </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="account/input" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <ul>
      {{form.as_ul}}
      </ul>
      <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

If any one can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpResponseRedirect('account/input')
```

you need to add one more '/' to the beginning like

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/account/input')
```

Comment: Thank you, I am now getting this error; RuntimeError at /account/input
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/account/input/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

Comment: simply add a trailing slash to back also.. **by default Django add trailing slash if you are using named url**, but right now you are using static url. so you need to add it manually. like `HttpResponseRedirect('/account/input/')`
i hope you learned a new thing today.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) so if you change the URL you don't have to change your code and you avoid mistakes entering the URL.

Instead of

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/account/input')
```

use

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_input'))
```

remember to add the import

```
from django.urls import reverse
```